# Value-initializing global variables at declaration

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, variable-assignment, variable-declaration

I have read some conflicting info about assigning values to global variables at declaration.

Some seem to allow this:

```
int g_int = 5;
```

while others say it must be initalized in main:

```
int g_int;
int main() { 
    g_int = 5; 
}
```

I personally have used the first style in Visual Studio 2008–2013 without any problems.

- Is this legal C++?
- If it isn't defined in C++, is it still compiler-defined behaviour in MSVC and g++?
- If it is legal, is assignment of a function result also legal, with the function call guaranteed to be executed before `main`? E.g. `time_t g_starttime = time();`?

Comment: `g_int = 5; ` is not initialization in main.  It is assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> others say it must be initialized in main

"Others" are wrong: although variables defined inside a translation unit certainly *could* be assigned in `main`, they don't *have to* be assigned in `main`.

This is perfectly legal in C++. Assignment of a function result also legal, and the initialization is guaranteed to happen before entering `main`.

Moreover, if you have multiple declarations with initialization inside the same translation unit (i.e. inside the same CPP file) they are guaranteed to be executed in textual order. If you do this

```
int twoTimes(int i) {
    cout << "Doubling " << i << endl;
    return 2*i;
}
int a = twoTimes(7);
int b = twoTimes(8);
int main() {
    ...
}
```

the output is guaranteed to be

```
Doubling 7
Doubling 8
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `int g_int = 5;` (and `int g_int;`) is not declaration, it's definition.

> Is this legal C++?

Yes, and `g_int` will be initialized with value `5`. (BTW: For `int g_int;` `g_int` will be initialized with value `0`.)

> If it is legal, is assignment of a function result also legal, with the function call guaranteed to be executed before main? E.g.
>   time_t g_starttime = time();?

Yes, it is guaranteed.

BTW: `g_int = 5;` in `main()` is not initialization, it's just assignment. It means that if `g_int` is used before `main()` entered, the default value `0` (not `5`) will be used.